# Piecewise random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given $A$ and $B$ are random variables with event $C$. Show that $X(x) = A(x)$ if $x\in C$, $X(x)= Y(x)$ if $x\in C^c$ is a random variable.

**My attempt** Let $D := \left\{A(x): x\in C\right\}$, and $E := \left\{Y(x): x\in C^c\right\}$. For any $T\subset \mathscr{B}(R)$, we have: $X^{-1}(T) = \emptyset$ if $D,E\not\subset T$, $X^{-1}(T)= C^{c}$ $(D,E\subset T)$, $X^{-1}(T)=C^c$ $(D\subset T, C\not\subset T)$, $X^{-1}(T)=C$ $(C\subset T, D\not\subset T)$.

**My question** Now, we still need to take care of the case when $D\cap T \neq \emptyset$. What does that case mean using the assumption that $A,B$ are random variables? Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowed to use the fact that sums and products of random variables are random variables, then note that 
$$X=A1_C+B1_{C^c}$$
where $1_C$ is the indicator random variable of the event $C$, i.e. $1_C(\omega)=1$ if $\omega\in C$, $1_C(\omega)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Brilliant solution! I'm so dumb not to see it. Could you please help me again with the following problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922186/sigma-algebra-of-borel-measurable-function.