# Absolute value of a function is random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Give an example to the statement: if $|X|$ is a random variable on $\omega$, $X$ is not a random variable.

I currently could not think of such example. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint: Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be $[0,1]$ with the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets, and let $\mathcal{N}$ be a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$.

Now define a function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $X$ takes one value on $\mathcal{N}$, and a different value on its complement. How could these values be chosen so that $X$ is not measurable but $|X|$ is?

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Should it be $X(x)= 1$ for any $x\in \mathscr{N}$, and $X(x)=-1$ for any $x\in \mathscr{N^c}$? Because this means $|X|$ is measurable as $|X|^{-1}(1) =  [0,1]$, which is measurable. But then $X^{-1}(1)= N$, which is non-measurable by our assumption. So we're done?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. Could you please help me with this problem as well? I don't see why I got stuck on this one, becaue it seems to be trivial given $A,B$ are already random variables defined on the same events as $X$ is. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921998/piecewise-random-variables.

Comment: my apology for this follow-up question. I just notice that the way you define $\mathscr{F}$ is of Lebesgue measurable sets, but for a random variable function, it should be Borel measurable set. These are two different things, but I'm not sure if the same proof in my first comment above works for Borel measurable rather than Lebesgue one. Any thought please?

Comment: A random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}$ for all Borel sets $B\subset\mathbb{R}$. In my example I chose $\Omega=[0,1]$ and $\mathcal{F}$ to be the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets. If this makes you queasy, feel free to change $\mathcal{F}$ to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and choose $\mathcal{N}$ to be a non-Borel set.

Comment: quite clear now. I'm not sure if there exists such a subset of $[0,1]$ which is non-Borel-measurable set? Is this a famous result, as in the case of Lebesgue measure for $[0,1]$?

Comment: The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is contained in the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, so a non-Lebesgue-measurable set will also not be a Borel set. But it turns out that there are Lebesgue-measurable sets that are not Borel sets as well.